# update the database using into sqlite

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am working on update query and i am using Bill Weinman library for sqlite database interaction so i want to update the database but native code  update only data by scenario id but i want to update respect upon the three more value and i am not able to figure out how can i do that, please help me. Tnx a lot.

this is the method called by controller object then by checking the value i manage the insert and update option

```
// Method to insert Scenario Product detail
- (void) insertScenarioProductAttribute: (NSMutableDictionary*) getRecord andOldProductAttribute:(NSDictionary*) oldRecord {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    self.tableName = ktnt_scenarioproductTableName;
    NSNumber* _checkScenarioid = [self valueFromQuery:@"select scenarioid from tnt_scenarioproduct WHERE scenarioid = ? AND weekvalue = ? AND productid = ?",
                                  [oldRecord objectForKey:@"scenarioid"], [oldRecord objectForKey:@"weekvalue"], [oldRecord objectForKey:@"productid"]];
    if (_checkScenarioid) {
        [self updateRow:getRecord :_checkScenarioid];
    } else {
        [self insertRow:getRecord];     // indicate that it's a new row
    }
}
```

then with this method i update the data but this was written only using by a single value "scenario id" but in that case my all data get update which i don't want

```
- (void) updateRow:(NSDictionary *) record:(NSNumber *) rowID {
     // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    int dictSize = [record count];

    // the values array is used as the argument list for bindSQL
    id keys[dictSize];  // not used, just a side-effect of getObjects:andKeys
    id values[dictSize + 1];
    [record getObjects:values andKeys:keys];    // convenient for the C array
    values[dictSize] = rowID;

    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update %@ set %@ = ? where scenarioid = ?",
                        tableName,
                        [[record allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@" = ?, "]];

    [self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] arguments:(va_list)values];
    sqlite3_step(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: Tnx and i try to explain more then that so you people can understand better, tnx a lot for suggestion.

Comment: Please reword that first paragraph into separate sentences.